# What is the largest possible sum of all the angle measures of a $\Delta$ in hyperbolic space?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

$\Delta ABC$ exists in hyperbolic geometry. What is the maximum value for $m\angle A+m\angle B+m\angle C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\pi- \epsilon$.

The sum of the angles of a hyperbolic triangle comes out to $\pi - Area(\Delta ABC)$, so by making the area close to zero, your angles will be close to $\pi$ (think of $\epsilon$ as a small constant).

On the other hand, by making a very large hyperbolic triangle, the angles approach zero and the sides are nearly parallel.  (Try this in a model of hyperbolic space, like the Poincare disc.)

Comment: So in hyperbolic space, angles are dependent on area? Also, any resources you recommend me look at regarding hyperbolic triangles?

Comment: The angles of a *triangle* are related to its area.  When you make the triangle very small, the local geometry is almost flat (just like very small areas of a sphere look flat).  In flat space, triangles' angles sum to $\pi$, so you get almost the same thing.

Going the other direction, as a vertex is pulled away from the others, its edges become nearly parallel.  In euclidean space you can do this with only a single vertex, but in hyperbolic space you have enough 'room' to do it with all three.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Poincare disc or plane?  Try forming a triangle in such a model and then drag its vertices towards the "boundary" to see the angles vanish as the area grows.

Comment: Also the exterior angle theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem , the WEAK version) is valid in hyperbolic geometry

Answer (score 1):

The area of a spherical triangle is given by
$${\rm area}(\triangle)={\rm angle\ sum}-\pi\ ,$$
and for a hyperbolic triangle we have
$${\rm area}(\triangle)=\pi-{\rm angle\ sum}(\triangle)\ .$$
Both formulas are a consequence of the famous Gauss-Bonnet theorem. It follows that in a hyperbolic triangle we have
$${\rm angle\ sum}(\triangle)=\pi-{\rm area}(\triangle)\ .$$
As such triangles can have arbitrary small area $>0$ there is no hyperbolic triangle of maximal area, but we can say that the supremum of the angle sums is $\pi$. Note that small triangles of arbitrary shape can approximate this supremum.